# Desajuste de Fechas en Validaciones PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5, phpmailer

Mi código PHP está experimentando un problema durante la validación de variables. Al imprimir los datos para su depuración, se observa que las variables contienen información correcta, especialmente la variable $fecha_fin. Sin embargo, al enviar el correo electrónico, se nota que la fecha en el mensaje difiere de la fecha obtenida en la consulta. Este desajuste es especialmente evidente en la fecha proporcionada en el mensaje del correo, ejemplo:

1. **fecha_actual:** 2024-02-02
2. **fecha_fin:** 2024-02-07
3. **numero_orden:** 1
4. **puntos_restantes:** 0
5. **correo_coordinador:** pruebaspuntos@hotmailcom

**El mensaje que llega al correo donde la fecha fin es errónea es el siguiente:**

[image: Error de fecha fin]

**El ejemplo de ese mensaje se encuentra en la // Validación 5**

```
// Validación 5
if (
  $fecha_actual > $fecha_fin
  && $puntos_restantes == 0
) {
  $fechaFinFormateada = $fecha_fin->format('Y-m-d');

  enviarCorreo(
    $correo_coordinador,
    "El colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']} asociado a la orden {$orden['numero_orden']}, la fecha fin de la orden caducó el día {$fechaFinFormateada} y tiene {$puntos_restantes} puntos."
  );
}
```

**Código completo:**

```
try {

  date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

// Consulta SQL
  $sql = "SELECT 
    os.id,
    cp.cedula,
    os.numero_orden,
    os.ceco,
    cp.nombre_colaborador,
    os.cantidad_puntos,
    ( os.cantidad_puntos - COALESCE(SUM(cp.puntos_asignados), 0) )
      AS puntos_restantes,
    cp.id_orden,
    os.fecha_fin,
    os.fecha_envio_correo,
    os.numero_contrato,
    os.id_usuario,
    us.correo,
    us.nombre_colaborador
      AS 'nombre de usuario',
    rl.nombre_rol
  FROM cantidad_puntos cp
  JOIN ordenes_servicios os
    ON cp.id_orden = os.id
  LEFT JOIN usuarios us ON us.id = os.id_usuario
  LEFT JOIN rol rl ON us.id_rol = rl.id_rol
  GROUP BY
    os.id,
    os.numero_orden,
    os.ceco,
    os.cantidad_puntos,
    os.fecha_fin,
    os.numero_contrato,
    os.id_usuario,
    us.correo,
    os.fecha_envio_correo,
    rl.nombre_rol;";

// Preparar la consulta
  $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);

// Ejecutar la consulta
  $stmt->execute();

// Obtener los resultados como un array asociativo
  $ordenes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Procesar las órdenes y realizar las validaciones
  foreach ($ordenes as $orden) {
  // Obtener valores relevantes
    $fecha_actual = new DateTimeImmutable();
    $id_servicio = $orden['id'];
    $fecha_fin = new DateTime($orden['fecha_fin']);
    $numero_orden = $orden['numero_orden'];
    $puntos_restantes = $orden['puntos_restantes'];
    $correo_coordinador = $orden['correo'];

// echo "fecha_actual: " . $fecha_actual->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
// echo "id_servicio: " . $id_servicio . "\n";
// echo "fecha_fin: " . $fecha_fin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
// echo "numero_orden: " . $numero_orden . "\n";
// echo "puntos_restantes: " . $puntos_restantes . "\n";
// echo "correo_coordinador: " . $correo_coordinador . "\n";
// exit();

// Validar si la fecha_envio_correo es menor a la fecha actual o es NULL
  if (
    is_null($orden['fecha_envio_correo'])
    || (new DateTime($orden['fecha_envio_correo']) < $fecha_actual)
  ) {
// Actualizar la columna fecha_envio_correo a la fecha actual
    $sqlUpdateFechaCorreo = "UPDATE
      ordenes_servicios os
      SET os.fecha_envio_correo = NOW()
      WHERE os.id = :id_servicio
        AND os.numero_orden = :numero_orden
        AND os.fecha_envio_correo IS NULL";
    $stmtUpdateFechaCorreo = $conexion->prepare($sqlUpdateFechaCorreo);
    $stmtUpdateFechaCorreo->bindParam(':id_servicio', $orden['id']);
    $stmtUpdateFechaCorreo->bindParam(':numero_orden', $orden['numero_orden']);
    $stmtUpdateFechaCorreo->execute();
  }

// Validar si la fecha_envio_correo es menor a la fecha actual
  if (
    new DateTime($orden['fecha_envio_correo']) < $fecha_actual
  ) {

    // Validación 1
    if (
      $fecha_actual < $fecha_fin
      && $fecha_actual >= $fecha_fin->modify('-6 days')
      && $puntos_restantes == ($orden['cantidad_puntos'] * 0.3)
    ) {
      enviarCorreo(
        $correo_coordinador,
        "La orden {$orden['numero_orden']} asociada al colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']}, aún tiene el 30% de {$orden['cantidad_puntos']} puntos sin consumir."
      );
    }

    // Validación 2
    if (
      $fecha_actual < $fecha_fin
      && $puntos_restantes == 0
    ) {
      enviarCorreo(
        $correo_coordinador,
        "El colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']} no tiene puntos disponibles para la orden {$orden['numero_orden']}."
      );
    }

    // Validación 3
    if (
      $fecha_actual === $fecha_fin
      && $puntos_restantes == 0
    ) {
      enviarCorreo(
        $correo_coordinador,
        "El colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']} asociado a la orden {$orden['numero_orden']} no tiene puntos disponibles."
      );
    }

    // Validación 4
    if (
      $fecha_actual < $fecha_fin
      && $fecha_actual <= $fecha_fin->modify('-5 days')
      && $puntos_restantes > 0
    ) {
      enviarCorreo(
        $correo_coordinador,
        "El colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']} asociado a la orden {$orden['numero_orden']} se encuentra a 5 días de la fecha final de la orden y los puntos restantes son {$puntos_restantes}."
      );
    }

    // Validación 5
    if (
      $fecha_actual > $fecha_fin
      && $puntos_restantes == 0
    ) {
      $fechaFinFormateada = $fecha_fin->format('Y-m-d');
      enviarCorreo(
        $correo_coordinador,
        "El colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']} asociado a la orden {$orden['numero_orden']}, la fecha fin de la orden caducó el día {$fechaFinFormateada} y tiene {$puntos_restantes} puntos."
      );
    }

    // Actualizar la columna fecha_envio_correo
    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE
      ordenes_servicios os
      SET os.fecha_envio_correo = NOW()
      WHERE os.id = :id_servicio
        AND os.numero_orden = :numero_orden";
    $stmtUpdate = $conexion->prepare($sqlUpdate);
    $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':id_servicio', $orden['id']);
    $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':numero_orden', $orden['numero_orden']);
    $stmtUpdate->execute();
    }
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  // Manejar errores de la base de datos
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hola, pon un `var_dump($fecha_fin);` en la validación y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano, me arrojo el siguiente resultado:
correos.js:17  Respuesta del servidor: object(DateTime)#6 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2024-02-07 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(14) "America/Bogota"
}
fecha_actual: 2024-02-02 13:51:26
id_servicio: 1
fecha_fin: 2024-02-07 00:00:00
numero_orden: 1
puntos_restantes: 0
correo_coordinador:

Comment: Declara el objeto como inmutable con **`$fecha_fin = new DateTimeInmutable($orden['fecha_fin']);`**, así, las llamadas a `modify()` no afectarán a tu fecha original. Para más detalles, revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetimeimmutable.php).

Answer (score 0):

Segun veo tu problema se debe a que estas modificando la variable `fecha_fin` en algunas de tus validaciones, particularmente en estas:

```
if (
  $fecha_actual < $fecha_fin
  && $fecha_actual >= $fecha_fin->modify('-6 days')
  && $puntos_restantes == ($orden['cantidad_puntos'] * 0.3)
) {
  enviarCorreo(
    $correo_coordinador,
    "La orden {$orden['numero_orden']} asociada al colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']}, aún tiene el 30% de {$orden['cantidad_puntos']} puntos sin consumir."
  );
}

if (
  $fecha_actual < $fecha_fin
  && $fecha_actual <= $fecha_fin->modify('-5 days')
  && $puntos_restantes > 0
) {
  enviarCorreo(
    $correo_coordinador,
    "El colaborador {$orden['nombre_colaborador']} asociado a la orden {$orden['numero_orden']} se encuentra a 5 días de la fecha final de la orden y los puntos restantes son {$puntos_restantes}."
  );
}
```

La función `modify` modifica el valor del objeto que la invoca es decir que tu variable `fecha_fin` está siendo modificada ([Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)), esto lo puedes resolver creando una variable auxiliar que contenga el valor original de fecha fin para evitar modificarlo, también debes tener en cuenta que al modificar el valor de manera consecutiva este se ira sumando a la fecha que tenga la variable, es decir que si la fecha es 2024-02-02 y le aplicas `$fecha_fin->modify('-6 days')` `fecha_fin` sera 2024-01-27 pero si ademas le haces  `$fecha_fin->modify('-5 days')` ahora su valor sera 2024-01-25, por lo que la variable que uses en tus validaciones debe reiniciarse al valor de `fecha_fin` antes de modificarla nuevamente.

Espero haber sido claro, saludos.

Comment: También puede usar `DateTimeInmutable()` en cuyo caso la llamada a `modify` crea un objeto nuevo sin modificar el original.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón lo olvide por completo.

Comment: @DaNiEl muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @A.Cedano  muchas gracias por la ayuda.